# Update Database with Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-context

In my react project i am updating the database every time some reducer state properties are being changed.

```
  useEffect(() => {
   //Updating db here
  }, [reducerState.table, reducerState.order, reducerState.bill, reducerState.liveCart, reducerState.occupency])
```

and I need to have this as and initial state when i reload the page so I am doing it with another useEffect
like this

```
useEffect(() => {
   //making db call to get the saved state
   //const newState = newState from db
   dispatch({
      type: "SET",
      payload: newState
   })
  }, [])
```

the backend is updating in first useEffect but after page refresh reducerState is changing back to initial state, i am new to this so i don't know why it is happening

Answer (score 1):

React's `state` and `reducer` will not retain their values after reloading the page. You have to use `localstorage` or `cookies` in order to achieve this.

Refer here for [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Refer here for [`cookies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: Yaa but i also want it to persist in database

Comment: You'll have to write an endpoint to update DB in the backend. Once the request is fired refreshing the page will not affect the request.